# Specify dependency version for Maven Archetype plugin

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I am currently working with Maven 3.3.3, from which the `mvn.bat` file has been removed. The recommended and only way to run Maven is now through the `mvn.cmd` file.

I am using a custom archetype that calls the maven-invoker plugin for some operation. [Note that the invoker plugin is a dependency of the Maven archetype plugin](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/dependency-management.html).

On `archetype:generate`, the invoker is called and throws an error :

> `Error configuring command-line. Reason: Maven executable not found at: <MAVEN_PATH>\bin\mvn.bat`

This issue seems to have been fixed with the release 2.2 of the invoker, but the last version of `maven-archetype-plugin` still uses an old version of it.

**How can I specify, in my archetype's POM, the version of the invoker plugin to use ?**

For now, I've tried to configure the plugin by adding this code into the archetype's POM file, but it had no effect, and didn't fixed the error.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-archetype</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**EDIT 1 :**
Here's the filtered stack trace.

```
[INFO] Invoking post-archetype-generation goals: com.company.my-custom-maven-plugin:uuid-generator
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.777 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-08T15:09:19+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/210M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Cannot run additions goals. Error configuring command-line. Reason: Maven executable not found at: <MAVEN_PATH>\bin\mvn.bat -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Cannot run additions goals.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot run additions goals.
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.invokePostArchetypeGenerationGoals(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenInvocationException: Error configuring command-line. Reason: Maven executable not found at: <MAVEN_PATH>\bin\mvn.bat
    at org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker.execute(DefaultInvoker.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.invokePostArchetypeGenerationGoals(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:237)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.CommandLineConfigurationException: Maven executable not found at: <MAVEN_PATH>\bin\mvn.bat
    at org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenCommandLineBuilder.findMavenExecutable(MavenCommandLineBuilder.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenCommandLineBuilder.build(MavenCommandLineBuilder.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker.execute(DefaultInvoker.java:101)
    ... 24 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug of the Maven Archetype Plugin: the JIRA issue is [ARCHETYPE-488](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-488). It affects all versions of the plugin ≤ 2.4 and is resolved with version 3.0.0.

Quoting [Jörg Hohwiller](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-488?focusedCommentId=15089212&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15089212) in the linked issue (dated 08-Jan-2016 13:47):

> > Is there a workaround for it?
>
> Yep. Just create a copy of "mvn.cmd" that you call "mvn.bat" in MAVEN_HOME/bin.

So a possible work-around with 2.4 or earlier is just to make a copy of the `mvn` executable with the other name.

Comment: Thanks ! We actually have tried that and it worked. But we need to distribute this archteype, and we cannot operate such changes on the client's computer. Would there be anything else ?

Comment: @Rems I'm afraid the problem is coming from the client itself. Thefore, we either need to wait for resolution of that bug or modify the client's computer. (Note that in the linked issue, someone tried your approach also but failed with the same error)

Comment: Sad :(
Sooo, I suppose the `<plugin>` section I added in the archetype's POM is never used because when performing an `archetype:generate` I am not actually running Maven on the POM itself, so these settings are not used in the running lifecycle ?

Comment: PS: (Merci de la part d'un collègue Sopra Steria Toulousain ;) )

Comment: @Rems I'm thinking exactly the same yes :)! (oh mais de rien! :D)

Comment: The ultimate solution would then be to advise a switch to 3.0.5 I guess

Comment: @Rems Would probably be more difficult to do on the client's machine than making a sim-link though.

Answer (score 2):

The bug references by [@Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) has been fixed (posting for reference) and the `pom.xml` needs:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <dependencies>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
     </dependency>
     </dependencies>
</plugin>
```